# Calculating Travelling Salesman - memory consumption and speed

Tags: java, algorithm, traveling-salesman

I need to implement the dynamic programming algorithm for the travelling salesman problem. My input is a text file with first line indicates the number of cities. Each city is a point in the plane, and each subsequent line indicates the x- and y-coordinates of a single city. The distance between two cities is defined as the Euclidean distance. The output of my program should be the minimum cost of a travelling salesman tour for this instance, rounded down to the nearest integer. I am having trouble coming up with ideas on how to reduce memory consumption and increase efficiency. The optimizations I have used are only storing subproblems of size m and size m-1 in an array.

Could someone advise me on possible improvements?

```
public class TSP {

static double [][] A;
static List<Integer> cities;
static int number_of_cities;
static List<Set<Integer>> myPowerSetPrevious;
static List<Set<Integer>> myPowerSetNext;
static int sizeTogether;

public static double distance (double x1, double y1, double x2, double y2){

    return Math.sqrt(Math.pow(x1-x2,2) + Math.pow(y1-y2,2));
}

private static void getSubsets(List<Integer> superSet, int k, int idx, Set<Integer> current,List<Set<Integer>> solution) {
    //successful stop clause
    if (current.size() == k) {
        Set<Integer> a = new HashSet<Integer>();
        a.addAll(current);
        solution.add(a);
        return;
    }
    //unseccessful stop clause
    if (idx == superSet.size()) return;
    Integer x = superSet.get(idx);
    current.add(x);
    //"guess" x is in the subset
    getSubsets(superSet, k, idx+1, current, solution);
    if (x != 1){
        current.remove(x);
        //"guess" x is not in the subset
        getSubsets(superSet, k, idx+1, current, solution);
    }
}

public static List<Set<Integer>> getSubsets(List<Integer> superSet, int k) {
    List<Set<Integer>> res = new ArrayList<Set<Integer>>();
    getSubsets(superSet, k, 0, new HashSet<Integer>(), res);
    return res;
}

public static void initialize(int k_start){

    int presize = myPowerSetPrevious.size(); // size of previous (1)
    int oldSize = sizeTogether;
    myPowerSetPrevious = myPowerSetNext;
    myPowerSetNext = getSubsets(cities,k_start);
    sizeTogether = myPowerSetPrevious.size() + myPowerSetNext.size();
    double [][] B = new double [sizeTogether][number_of_cities + 1];

    int count = 0;
    for (int i = presize; i < oldSize; i ++){
        for (int j = 1; j <= number_of_cities; j++){
            B[count][j] = A[i][j];
        }
        count++;
    }
    presize = myPowerSetPrevious.size();
    for (int i = presize; i < sizeTogether; i++){
        B[i][1] = Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY;
    }
    A = B;

}

/**
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String inputFileName = "src\\tsp.txt";
    In in = new In(inputFileName);
    number_of_cities = in.readInt();
    double [][] xy_points = new double [number_of_cities + 1][2];
    cities = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    for (int i =1; i < number_of_cities + 1; i ++){
        xy_points[i][0] = in.readDouble();
        xy_points[i][1] = in.readDouble();
        cities.add(i);
    }
    myPowerSetPrevious = getSubsets(cities,1);
    myPowerSetNext = getSubsets(cities,2);

    sizeTogether = myPowerSetPrevious.size() + myPowerSetNext.size();
    A = new double [sizeTogether][number_of_cities + 1]; // j's for each S
    for (int i = 0; i < myPowerSetPrevious.size(); i++){
        if (myPowerSetPrevious.get(i).size() == 1 & myPowerSetPrevious.get(i).contains(1)){
            A[i][1] = 0;
        }
        else
            A[i][1] = Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY;
    }
    for (int i = myPowerSetPrevious.size(); i < sizeTogether; i++){
        A[i][1] = Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY;
    }

    int k_start = 2;
    //initialize(k_start);



    int count = myPowerSetPrevious.size();
    while (count < sizeTogether){//Set<Integer> s : myPowerSetNext){ // for each subset S

        Set<Integer> s =  myPowerSetNext.get(count - myPowerSetPrevious.size());
        if (s.size() >= 2 & s.contains(1)){

            for (Integer j : s){ // for each j vertex
                if (j != 1){
                    Set<Integer> newSet = new HashSet<Integer>();
                    newSet.addAll(s);
                    newSet.remove(j);
                    int index = myPowerSetPrevious.indexOf(newSet);
                    double minDist = -1;
                    for (Integer k : s){
                        if (k != j){
                            double dist =  A[index][k] + distance(xy_points[k][0], xy_points[k][1], xy_points[j][0], xy_points[j][1]);
                            if (minDist == -1){
                                minDist = dist;
                            }
                            else if (minDist > dist){
                                minDist = dist;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    //System.out.println("S: " + s + " j: " + j + " " + " = " + minDist);
                    A[count][j] = minDist;
                }
            }
        }
        count++;
        if (count >= A.length){
            k_start ++;
            //System.out.println("K_start: " + k_start);
            initialize(k_start);
            //System.out.println("length: " + myPowerSetNext.size());
            count = myPowerSetPrevious.size();
        }

    }
    double minDist = -1;
    for (int j = 2; j <= number_of_cities; j ++){
        double dist = A[A.length - 1][j] + distance(xy_points[j][0], xy_points[j][1], xy_points[1][0], xy_points[1][1]);
        if (minDist == -1)
            minDist = dist;
        else if (minDist > dist){
            minDist = dist;
        }
    }
    System.out.println("minDist: " + minDist);
}
```

Comment: what is `A` and what is `B`.  then Why are you using `Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY` it looks like you are assigning a value of infinity to a lot of members in both of those arrays.

Answer (score 4):

The optimization I have used so far is storing subproblems of size m and size m-1 in HashMaps separately including only subsets with 1st vertex. E.g. For m = 1, there is only {1} subset. The keys of this HashMap are BitSets as used to represent subsets. I also used Gosper's Hack to get the next subset with same number of m bits, putting new BitSet key and double[] value in the HashMap for m, this way increasing efficiency by generating subsets iteratively.

As well, I created an adjacency matrix of distances (n x n) based on the number of cities to use for lookup, which also increases efficiency.